# JSX Curly Braces Inside Script Tag?

Tags: javascript, jsx, mithril.js

This is a silly question but it's stumped me for a while now. I'm currently trying to design a Mithril.js component that returns a `<div>` object that includes a `<script>` tag. I've just trying to perform a couple tests and so far, my `view()` method, looks something like the following:

```
view() {
    return (<div>
        <script>
            var x = 5;
            alert(x);
            var y = {"a" : 1, "b": 3}; // Compiler complains about the curly braces in this line
        </script>
    </div>);
}
```

and everything seems find until the line where I try to define an object, where the compiler complains about the curly braces in that line. My VS Code editor asked if I meant to replace the braces with `{'{'}` and `{'}'}` or `&lbrace;` and `&rbrace;`, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem either. Is there some sort of way to include curly braces inside the `<script>` tag inside JSX?

Comment: `{'{'}` and `{'}'}` **are** how you do it.

Comment: Dynamically generating a `<script>` element with JS seems *really* hinky though.

Comment: If you need to do this, there is something wrong with the logic.

Comment: @epscarello Could you explain why this is not recommended?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML, however it is not recommended.

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
            var x = 5;
            alert(x);
            var y = {"a" : 1, "b": 3};
        `,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Wrong - that's how you do it in React, not Mithril.

Answer (score 2):

You include literal `{` and `}` in JSX by doing `{'{'}` (an interpolation with a single-character string) and `{'}'}` as applicable.

But in either case, you shouldn't need to use a `<script>` in a view *ever*. The view is already in JS - just use component state for that.